# forkIO seems to block on haskell websocket server

Tags: multithreading, haskell, threadscope

I'm running a haskell websocket server using Wai:

```
application :: MVar ServerState -> Wai.Application
application state = WaiWS.websocketsOr WS.defaultConnectionOptions wsApp staticApp
  where
    wsApp :: WS.ServerApp
    wsApp pendingConn = do
      conn <- WS.acceptRequest pendingConn 
      talk conn state
```

To allow a single client to send asynchronous messages, talk is defined as follows:

```
talk :: WS.Connection -> MVar ServerState -> IO ()
talk conn state = forever $ do
  msg <- WS.receiveMessage conn

  putStrLn "received message"

  successLock <- newEmptyMVar 
  tid <- timeoutAsync successLock $ processMessage c state msg

  putStrLn "forked thread"

  modifyMVar_ state $ \curState -> 
    return $ curState & threads %~ (M.insert mid tid) -- thread bookkeeping

  putStrLn "modified state"

  putMVar successLock ()
  putStrLn "unlocked success"

  where
    mid                 = serverMessageId msg
    timeoutAsync lock f = forkIO $ do
      timeout S.process_message_timeout onTimeout (onSuccess lock) f
    onSuccess lock      = do
      -- block until the first modifyMVar_ above finishes.
      takeMVar lock
      modifyMVar_ state $ \curState -> 
        return $ curState & threads %~ (M.delete mid) -- thread cleanup
    onTimeout = ...
```

Here's the thing: when I bombard this server with many messages (from a single client) that are CPU-heavy, the **the main thread occasionally hangs at "forked thread"**.

This is surprising because all work on messages are (in theory) being done in separate threads, and so the main thread (`forever`) **should never block**.

What's going on here?

[EDIT]

A minimum verifiable example is pretty hard to provide in this case (the work is done in `processMessage`, but  comprises a lot of moving parts, any of which might be the problem). Instead, I'm looking for high-level pointers to things I could investigate.

*Here is data from an example run* (send the server an expensive request, then a bunch of smaller less-expensive ones):

- gc productivity 36%: http://puu.sh/nSxnj/d8bb5995ae.png
- event log (using `+RTS -ls` and `-eventlog`): http://puu.sh/nSxDy/efe457bee2.eventlog
- CPU usage ~300% (for 4 caps) -- made me think GC might be competing with OS resources; I decreased the num capabilities to `n-1`, and this seemed to improve responsiveness

Also, the app has the following properties, which I think are potential causes of the problem:

- ratio of GC'd to live data is high; `processMessage` basically constructs a giant list which is `aeson'd` and sent back to the user, but not kept in state
- many foreign calls are made (due to [ZMQ](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zeromq4-haskell-0.6/docs/System-ZMQ4-Monadic.html), which iirc makes unsafe foreign calls) on a single request
- ThreadScope tells me that lots of heapoverflows occur, causing GC requests

Comment: are you ever doing a `putMVar` or `takeMVar` on your `state` MVar outside of this code?

Comment: nope, neither one.

Comment: you may need to provide a self-contained runnable example if you want help debugging this

Comment: Where does the computation happen? I don't see it in your example.

Comment: To get help, you'll need a minimum complete verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite difficult to provide an mcve because there are tons of moving parts in `processMessage` and I don't really know which direction to look yet. I've provided data from a sample run that might indicate weird behavior I'm not seeing.

Comment: when you say "hangs" do you mean permanently like a deadlock? Or just pauses longer than you'd expect between "forked thread" and "modified state"?